# How to try if lines in a file match with lines in an other file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, variables, match, brute-force

How do I "brute" every line in a file Until I find what matches it, what I mean is I turned every line in `save.data` and `brute.txt` into two lists (For easy access), here is `brute.txt`:

```
username
username1
password
password1
```

And here is `save.data` (Since this is for a Batch-file game, there is no need to quote strings like "username1"):

```
username1 = PlayerName
password1 = PlayerPass
```

So, my request is, I want to try if line 1 from `brute.txt` matches the the thing before the equal sign in `save.data` (which is 'username1'), if it doesn't match with it pass to the next line, and so on until it reaches the end of the file (`save.data`) then try if line 2 from `brute.txt` matches line 1 from `save.data` (which matches) if not, pass to if line 2 from `brute.txt` matches the thing before the qual sign in line 2 in `save.data` and so on ... And finally, when "username" matches "username", make a variable called `username` with the value of what is after the equal sign in `save.data`. So, when the "bruting" process is finished, I must have two variables, one is `username = PlayerName` and the other is `password = PlayerPass` for further use. I tried while, for and try loops but I got stuck because to do so I need to know what is in `save.data`.

-If you didn't understand something, kindly comment it and I will clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but to answer the question you asked..

First open the `save.data` file and read the contents into a list:

```
with open('save.data') as fp:
    save_data = [line.split(' = ') for line in fp.read().splitlines()]
```

do the same for the `brute.txt` file:

```
with open('brute.txt') as fp:
    brute = fp.read().splitlines()
```

then just iterate through usernames and passwords:

```
for username, password in save_data:
    if username in brute:
        break
else:
    print("didn't find the username")
```

the `username` and `password` variables from the for-loop will have the correct values after the for-loop breaks.

(please note that the `else:` is on the for-loop, not the if..)